# How to manual confirm (ack) message at consumer side in spring cloud stream 3.2.4

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, mq

My code, its use function programing model

```java
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> test() {
        return msg -> {
          // how to confirm ack manually
        };
    }
```

Comment: Which binder are you using?

Comment: Hi, I used rabbit, thanks for your reply